# SQL writing query to fulfill two requirements

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a practice problem where I need to write a query that shows all top 100 songs from 1985 to 1990. I tried the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM billboard.chart 
WHERE year BETWEEN 1985 AND 1990
LIMIT 100
```

But it seems like the table contains a tie, so that only gives me until rank 96. I tried using two WHERE clauses, but this gives me an error.

```
SELECT * FROM billboard.chart 
WHERE year BETWEEN 1985 AND 1990
WHERE year_rank BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

How should I go about extracting both certain time period and certain ranks?

Comment: `year between 1985 and 1990 and year_rank between 1 and 100`

Comment: I posted it as an answer, please feel free to mark it as an accepted solution. Thanks.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the expected output.

```
SELECT * FROM billboard.chart 
WHERE year BETWEEN 1985 AND 1990
AND year_rank BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

You can explore default `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` function within MySQL, it gives you more flexibility on how to handle ties.